# Building Jagged Tree With Parentless Nodes In C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, .net-4.5

I have a set of lists of related items that I need to create a tree structure from. However some of these tree nodes are parentless and I want to stick each of these nodes into the root. Using LINQ and my results I have created the following. However this cannot deal with nodes that have no parent in branches....

```
        var list = 
            (from o in resultList[QueryList.Length - 1].ToList()
            select new GroupItem
            {
                ItemCode = o.ItemCode,
                ItemDescription = o.ItemDescription,
                Items = (from tg in resultList[QueryList.Length - 2].ToList()
                        where tg.ParentCode == o.ItemCode
                        select new GroupItem
                        {
                            ItemCode = tg.ItemCode,
                            ItemDescription = tg.ItemDescription,
                            Items = (from t in resultList[QueryList.Length - 3]
                                    where t.ParentCode == tg.ItemCode
                                    select new GroupItem
                                    {
                                        ItemCode = t.ItemCode,
                                        ItemDescription = t.ItemDescription,
                                        Items = (from su in resultList[QueryList.Length - 4]
                                                where su.ParentCode == t.ItemCode
                                                select new SelectableItem
                                                {
                                                    ItemCode = su.ItemCode,
                                                    ItemDescription = su.ItemDescription,
                                                }).ToList()
                                    }).Cast<SelectableItem>().ToList()
                        }).Cast<SelectableItem>().ToList()
            }).Cast<SelectableItem>().ToList();
```

what I really want is... is there a way to do this quickly and easily with LINQ to Objects?

```
Root
^
|
|____Node 1
|         |
|         |<------ Parent Relationship
|________Node 2
|             |
|             |  
|____________Node 3
   ^
   |
   |
   If no parent then add to root.
```

Comment: Your code could use some cleanup.. I assume `resultList` is a list of lists of some sort? Where does `QueryList` come from?

Comment: result list is an array of lists and query list is the input query list. At some point I will have to adapt the code to allow of any depth of tree depending on the length of this query list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do something like this:

```
List<List<GroupItem>> resultList = ...

var roots = new List<GroupItem>();

ICollection<GroupItem> parentLevel = roots;
foreach (var nodeLevel in resultList.AsEnumerable().Reverse())
{
    //Find each parent's child nodes:
    foreach (var parent in parentLevel)
    {
        parent.Items = nodeLevel.Where(node => node.ParentCode == parent.ItemCode)
                                .Cast<SelectableItem>().ToList();
    }

    //Add parentless nodes to the root:
    roots.AddRange(nodeLevel.Where(node => node.ParentCode == null));

    //Prepare to move to the next level:
    parentLevel = nodeLevel;
}
```

Comment: Ok. This is what i had sketched in my head, but couldn't work out how the algorithm would work. But it's quite simple I guess. Build the roots. Then starting at the base look for parent if none exist add to root otherwise continue up the tree.

Comment: Now I just have to work out the polymorphism... so the tree is built of the right types :P !

Comment: Yes, it gets a little more complicated if for example `resultList` doesn't contain `GroupItem`s, but the level-by-level-search principle stays the same :)

Answer (score 0):

After you've done all that just do:

```
resultList.ForEach(x => x.Where(tg => tg.ParentCode == null).ToList().ForEach(list.Add));
```

Comment: This wouldn't work as the sub branches of the tree that have no parent would not be built. Therefore the children of those parentless nodes would not be included in the tree.

Comment: This isn't touching any sub branches.  It is querying every item in each list for any items which have no parent id